# Flutter local persistence of Maps using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm an amateur coding doing my first flutter project. It's a simple word of the day app where one can write sentences of the words to remember them. The app then stores these sentences in an ExpandedTile with words as heading and sentences as subtitles. However, I've been running into some problems with persisting this information locally on phone. I've tinkered with a lot of options and have tried path provider and shared preferences.Here the words object is a Map with all the words and meanings and Savedwords is the map with words as keys and sentences as values. Currently using shared preferences shows this error:

```
    E/flutter ( 1223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
E/flutter ( 1223): #0      _SavedprefState.addString.<anonymous closure>
package:to_dolist/widgets/sharedpreflist.dart:22
E/flutter ( 1223): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 1223): #2      _SavedprefState.addString
package:to_dolist/widgets/sharedpreflist.dart:22
E/flutter ( 1223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1223):
E/flutter ( 1223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 1223): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 1223): Tried calling: iterator
E/flutter ( 1223): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 1223): #1      _SavedprefState.getString
package:to_dolist/widgets/sharedpreflist.dart:30
E/flutter ( 1223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1223):
```

I was hoping you guys could help out with this error with the code given below. I've given more than necessary code here if that can help garner a more efficient solution to this persistence problem. I've been stuck on this problem for a few months now, would really help me if you could give coded solutions here. This is the main dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_dolist/screens/HomePage.dart';
import './words.dart';
import './widgets/all.dart';
import './screens/secondscreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  final saveword = TextEditingController();

  var index = 0;
  void nextword() {
    saveword.clear();
    setState(() {
      if (index == words.length) {
        //index == words.length;
      } else {
        index++;
      }
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    saveword.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void prevword() {
    saveword.clear();
    setState(() {
      if (index == 0) {
      } else {
        index--;
      }
    });
    //return index;
  }

  void onTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> screens = [
      HomePage(index, nextword, prevword, saveword),
      SecondPage(saveword)
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(),
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
                    title: RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 50,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(text: 'Word of \n     ', style: TextStyle()),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: '     The Day',
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    toolbarHeight: 130,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    elevation: 4,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  body: screens[currentIndex],
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                    elevation: 100,
                    //backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
                    currentIndex: currentIndex,
                    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.today),
                          label: 'Word of The Day',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                          label: 'History',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey),
                    ],
                    onTap: onTapped,
                  ),
                  floatingActionButtonLocation:
                      FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
                  floatingActionButton: Fab(saveword, index),
                )));
  }
}
```

This is the Homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_dolist/widgets/all.dart';

@override
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  //const ({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;
  final Function nextword;
  final Function prevword;
  final control;
  HomePage(this.index, this.nextword, this.prevword, this.control);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: 500,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            child: WordColumn(index),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: control,
              onChanged: (text) => {},
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              minLines: 2,
              maxLines: 30,
            ),
          ),
          NavigateWords(nextword, prevword),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
          /*ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('history'),
            onPressed: Storage.readCounter ,
          )*/
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the second page dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_dolist/words.dart';
import './fab.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Savedpref extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditingController control;
  Savedpref(this.control);
  //const Savedpref({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SavedprefState createState() => _SavedprefState();
}

class _SavedprefState extends State<Savedpref> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> savedlist = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var written, read, values;
  List<Widget> savedhistory = [];
  Future<Null> addString() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await savedlist;
    Fab.savedwords
        .forEach((key, value) => {prefs.setStringList(key, value)});
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<Null> getString() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await savedlist;
    var keys = prefs.getKeys();
    keys.forEach((element) => {read.add(element)});
    for (var k in read) {
      values.add(prefs.get(k));
    }
    for (var j = 0; j <= keys.length; j++) {
      savedhistory.add(new ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(read[j], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        subtitle: Text(words[j].value, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(values[j]),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
    setState(() {});
    //keys.add(prefs.getKeys());
    //prefs.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      written = [];
      read = [];
    }

    return Stack(children: [
      ListView.separated(
          reverse: true,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          separatorBuilder: (context, i) => Container(
                //color: Colors.greenAccent,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 8,
              ),
          itemCount: savedhistory.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => Dismissible(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                  setState(() {
                    savedhistory.removeAt(i);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                  child: savedhistory[i],
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                ),
                /* read == null
            ? []
            : read.map((e) => ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(e),
                  subtitle: Text(e),
                )), */
              )),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () => getString(),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.replay_outlined),
              onPressed: addString,
            )),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

This is the Floating action button (Fab) widget code:

```
import 'package:to_dolist/words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:to_dolist/widgets/sharedpreflist.dart';
//import 'dart:convert';

class Fab extends StatelessWidget {
  static List history = <Widget>[];
  static Map savedwords = Map();
  /* void save1() {
    savedwords[words[index].key] = control.text;
    Storage.writeCounter();
  }*/

  void save() {
    savedwords[words[index].key] = control.text;
    //addString();
    //print(savedwords);*/
    /*history.add(new ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(
        words[index].key,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(words[index].value, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(control.text),
          ],
        )
      ],
      //tileColor: Colors.white,
      //shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      //side: BorderSide(width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
    )); */
  }

  //final Function save;
  final int index;
  final control;
  Fab(this.control, this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: save,
        label: const Text('Save'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[200],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error comes from this block here

```
 Future<Null> addString() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await savedlist;
    Fab.savedwords
        .forEach((key, value) => {prefs.setStringList(key, value)});
    setState(() {});
  }
```

In your `SavePrefs` state.

this line to be precise

```
Fab.savedwords
        .forEach((key, value) => {prefs.setStringList(key, value)});
```

I believe you are looping through a list of strings and want to persist each string to local storage. But you called the `setStringList` function of your sharedpreferences. This function requires that the `value` be a list of strings but because of your loop what you're actually passing as `value` is a single string.
Thus the error

> Unhandled Exception: type String' is not a subtype of type 'List'.

What it's saying is you cannot pass a string as parameter to a function that is looking for a List of Strings (i.e. "name" is different from ['name']).